# "Expect: 100-Continue" and... how a server tell the client it wish to receive the body and discard it?

Tags: http, network-protocols

HTTP Protocol: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26.html#header.expect

> - A server that responds with a final status code before reading the entire message body SHOULD indicate in that response whether it intends to close the connection or continue reading and discarding the request message

If the server wish to close the connection it will include "Connection: close" in his response. But how can it tell the client it wish to continue reading and discarding the body ? I don't know any header to do that.

And if it receive the body and discard it, this doesnt mean that "100-Continue" is useless ? That's the whole point of "100-Continue", not sending the body if it will be rejected anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When the server sends its *final* reply, it has finished processing the request. If the server sends that reply while the client is still sending its data, the client should stop sending, and then the presense of an HTTP  keep-alive (an explicit `Connection: keep-alive` header in an HTTP  1.0 reply, or a missing `Connection: close` header in an HTTP 1.1 reply) is the server's indication that it will be discarding any remaining data that is sent, since it needs to clear the socket of pending data before it can receive a new request on the same connection.

The `100-Continue` is not useless. Think of what happens when the server sends `100` to let the client start sending, then later errors and decides to stop receiving and send a *final* reply reporting the error. The server did not know at the start of the request that it was going to error.